# jpa many to many unique=true, how to save

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have three table

```
article(id, title, content)
article_tag(article_id, tag_id)
tag(id, name) // name(unique=true)
```

Article.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String content;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "article_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "article_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    private Timestamp createdAt;

    private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

Tag.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I know how to insert articles, but how can I insert duplicate tags?

Table tag already have ("a", "b", "c")

[image]

I want to insert a article with tag "a", how to do?

Comment: You should replaced Set to List. Everything is fine

Comment: Probably Set is better implementation in this problem @GauravSrivastav I belive author has different understanding of "duplicate tag"

Comment: @JacekCz I have two articles A, B three tags a,b,c A has tags a,b,c. B has tags a. I want to insert B after A, how to do it?

Comment: ... and an Tag is asiigned to Article 0 or 1 times (not more). So my opinion Set is good.

Comment: maybe you need method like `@Transactional Tag findOrCreate(String key)`, and resolved Tag add to Set

Comment: @JacekCz I try it, but `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`, I craete a method in service public Tag findOrCreate(String name) {
        if(tagRepository.existsByName(name)) {
            return tagRepository.findByName(name);
        }
        return new Tag(name);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I finish it by `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"tags"})` and `@ToString(exclude = {"tags"})`.

Stackoverflow Error was finished.

Also, I use `findOrCreate` to solve the problem of how to save unique column.